# Proper way to nest error messages while making asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, error-handling

When I make a synchronous jQuery ajax request, I need the ability to delay displaying the error message to the user until I can add some more information that does not exist in the context of my error function.  I'm trying to find a way to throw the information collected about the exception so that it can be caught higher up the chain and and be displayed with more meaningful information to the user.  I'm finding that even with synchronous requests, when I put a throw statement inside my error function that it is not caught by my wrapping catch block.

```
      function GetFileName(entity, field, guid){
  var filename;
  try 
    {
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: myURLwashere,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                var result = data.d;
                filename = result[field];
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                throw  textStatus + " " + errorThrown;
                //entity, field and guid are null here
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err){
        //this catch block does not catch the exception thrown by the error function.
        throw "Error Getting File Name from web service for entity '" + entity + "' field '" + field + "' and guid '" + guid + "' (" + err.message + ")";
    }
    return filename;
  }
```

This is a very simple example.  I could be nested through several functions several layers deep and want to add to the error message multiple times before displaying it to the user.

**Update**
I've updated the question to reflect my end-goal (nested error handling) without requiring that the solution be synchronous, which has been discouraged.

Comment: The answer to this is easy; you shouldn't be doing synchronous ajax calls at all.

Comment: About synchronous requests: *Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.* (from mdn).

Comment: Understood.  How about some recommendations for how to properly aggregate good error messages in nested calls with an asynchronous request instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this in response to the Troy's question in the comments, "How about some recommendations for how to properly aggregate good error messages in nested calls with an asynchronous request instead?"

If you've not done much event-driven (asynchronous) programming before, it does take a little getting used to. Find yourself a good online tutorial like this one:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027. If you're just starting out you might want to avoid getting into the Deferred or Promise model of asynchronous programming. Those are great tools, but callbacks are an easier way to start out.

One way to transform your code to be asynchronous is to give your function two extra "callback function" parameters:

```
function GetFileName(entity, field, guid, onSuccess, onError){
```

Now change `async` to true and modify the success and errors functions like this:

```
        async: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var result = data.d;
            filename = result[field];
            onSuccess( filename );
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // REMOVE: throw  textStatus + " " + errorThrown;
            //entity, field and guid are null here
            onError(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
```

Then remove the `catch` block and the `return` statement.

This style will cause you to rework or maybe even redesign some of your current code base. But as others have pointed out, using synchronous ajax calls can create a really poor user experience.

Comment: Lee.  I understand how you can pass a function that should be called when errors are thrown.  My Synchronous brain is having a hard time understanding how I can get behavior like nested error handling though.  If I have some data at the time the request is made that I want to use in the event that the request errors out, what is the best way to persist this?  For example I want to wrap the ugly textStatus with a nice message like "Unable to get file name for entity '123321'"  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Troy, you should be able to pass the `entity` as a parameter to the onError function. I see in your original code that there is a comment that entity is null when the error handler executes. This seems odd because the error function is declared in the closure context of GetFileName. Check out this jsfiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/kjsg4kkp/3/